# How to fill a slice of an array with numbers sampled from another array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a (very) big grayscale image and a mask, both ranging from 0 to 1, stored as numpy arrays. The mask is full of 0s and 1s. I would like to turn all 1 pixels in the mask to resemble some noise from the image, which was already sampled to vector `p`.

I've tried `mask[mask == 1] = np.random.choice(p)`, but of course it fills the whole area with only one of the values in `p`. I would like to avoid a for loop, and I would like to avoid creating a new image filled entirely from `p`, as they are really big for my tiny laptop.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try to generate the random choice with `size`:

```
mask[mask==1] = np.random.choice(p, size=mask.sum())
```